# seaborn plotting functions - when should we create a figure and axes beforehand?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to understand when seaborn will generate its plot on an axes created explicitly by me and when it will ignore any figure or axes that I generated beforehand. Do we only need to create a figure and an axes when the plotting function generates **individual plots**? What I mean by this is that the box plot or the violin plot generates **one** plot. For example, this snippet here creates a figure and an axes then fills it up with the boxplot.

```
figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(24, 4))
sb.boxplot(hp, orient = "h") 
plt.show()
```

[image]

This snippet however, creates an empty figure **and** another figure containing the joint plot. Is it because the joint plot generates **multiple** plots? Hence it ignores the figure and axes I just created? Because it has an inbuilt routine that generates its own figure and axes then fills it up?

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(24, 12))
sb.jointplot(x = attack, y = hp, height = 8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have looked through the docs but I just want to get a layman's understanding.

Comment: Correct. Some seaborn functions create a figure. Those are refered to as "Figure-level" functions in the documentation.